# Load JavaScript file via AJAX without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am dynamically loading a widget from another webservice that requires a script to be run immediately after it. The example uses document.write() to do this, but this does not work because it doesn't run until after the document has been closed, which means it overwrites the entire document. I am trying to load it via AJAX using pure JavaScript:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { // success
    eval(this.responseText);
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://d3gxy7nm8y4yjr.cloudfront.net/js/embed.js", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/javascript');
xhttp.send();
```

but I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://d3gxy7nm8y4yjr.cloudfront.net/js/embed.js. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I was able to make it work using jQuery on my test server with this code:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true,
    url: "https://d3gxy7nm8y4yjr.cloudfront.net/js/embed.js"
});
```

However, I cannot use jQuery on my production server because... well... work politics.

How is jQuery accomplishing this without an error, and how can I do it in pure JavaScript?

### Solution

As stated by @shabs, `$.ajax` adds a script tag to the `document.head` and then immediately removes it. I checked this by adding a breakpoint and saw it added and removed in Chrome's inspector. It appears to remove the file as soon as the current script completes regardless of what the file is. This works well for immediately invoked scripts, but I don't know how this would work with something like a library.

For a pure JavaScript implementation I used the following code:

```
var widgetScript = document.createElement("script");
widgetScript.async = true;
widgetScript.src = "https://d3gxy7nm8y4yjr.cloudfront.net/js/embed.js";
document.head.append(widgetScript);
widgetScript.remove();
```

Comment: append the script tag to the page....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource in question doesn't support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

This works through `$.ajax` because when you specify `dataType: "script"`, jQuery actually appends a `<script>` tag to `document.head`! *

Is there a particular reason you're not just using something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3gxy7nm8y4yjr.cloudfront.net/js/embed.js"></script>`?

* *(This is news to me! The [documentation for `$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) mentions that "script [...] requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions", and [the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js) confirms this.)*

Comment: I can't use a hard coded `<script>` tag is because the script is an immediately invoked anonymous function that must run every time I change the `<iframe>` that contains the widget.